# EmberJS retrieve current user from ember-simple-auth authenticator

Tags: javascript, authentication, ember.js, ember-data, ember-simple-auth

**Issue:**

I am trying to retrieve the current user logged in from ember-simple-auth by extending `ember-simple-auth/authenticators/base`. I just want to create a function called `currentUser()` that will return the username but I get the error whenever I try calling the function:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.get(...).currentUser is not a function(…)
```

**Attempt:**

the function `currentUser()` is defined below:

```
// app/authenticators/oauth2.js
import Ember from 'ember';
import Base from 'ember-simple-auth/authenticators/base';

const RSVP = Ember.RSVP;

export default Base.extend({
  restore() {
      // restore user session
  },
  currentUser() {
      return this.get("username");
  }),
  authenticate(username, password) {
    this.set('username', username);
    return new RSVP.Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      Ember.$.ajax({
        url: config.baseURL + "accounts/login",
        data: {
          username: username,
          password: password
        },
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        complete: (response)=> {
          if (response.responseJSON.isAuthenticated)
            resolve({isAuthenticated: true});
          else
            reject("Wrong credentials.");
        }
      });
    });
  },
  invalidate() {
    // log out
  }
});
```

I called the function using:

```
// app/controllers/application.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  session: Ember.inject.service('session'),

  actions: {
    alertSession() {
      console.log("!! " + this.get('session').currentUser());
    },
    invalidateSession() {
      this.get('session').invalidate();
      this.transitionToRoute('login');
    }
  }
});
```

`this.get('session').invalidate();` works, but `this.get('session').currentUser();` will return the error mentioned above.
Please let me know how to fix this.
Also, I am using Ember 2.5.1.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your application controller, you are calling `currentUser()` from the **session** service, while you’ve defined `currentUser()` in your **oauth2.js** authenticator.  Execution could be failing because you have not modified the **session** service to have a reference to your authenticator's `currentUser` function.

The other function executes successfully because the **session** service has the reference that is necessary to invoke the designated authenticator's `invalidate()` function.

You might consider using ember-simple-auth's suggestions for [Managing a Current User](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/blob/master/guides/managing-current-user.md#managing-a-current-user). With this, you can explore a solution that utilizes an isolated **currentUser** service that works in conjunction with the **session** service.

Comment: Oh wow I never realized ember-simple-auth had its own currentUser. Thanks so much!

Comment: By any chance do you know why inside app/services/current-user.js (from the link you sent me) gives an error saying "No model was found for 'user'"? Sorry I am new to ember.

Comment: In Ember, Ember Data helps to save and retrieve data, to and from your server. A **model** ["defines the attributes, relationships, and behavior of the data that you present to the user."](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.5.0/models/#toc_models) It looks as though you need to create a [`user` model in your app, like this](https://ember-twiddle.com/ce25a4c6497906e95a87eff95ad410ec?openFiles=models.user.js%2C).